# How extract TileMatrixSet from GeoServer in order to pass it to create WMTSTileService?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wmts, getcapabilities, getmap

I am trying to mock GetMap requests and had an issue on how to create valid BBox values for the requests so they would HIT the cached layer. I got an answer from Ian Turton [How properly calculate BBox for mocked GetMap request?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266118/how-properly-calculate-bbox-for-mocked-getmap-request) on how to calculate valid BBox but I. However I need to automate this process and parsing WMTS capabilities document is not what I would like to do. Ian's suggested usage of WMTS instead of WMS has a drawback - I need to know rows and columns for each zoom level I want to hit and I want to hit specific area only. I see no easy way to automate correct zoom level/column/row combination selection. 
  What I think is the best way to generate correct BBox parameters for GetMap requests is to call `org.geotools.data.wmts.client.WMTSTileFactory.findTileAtCoordinate(...)` with the random coordinates I can easily generate. Later I would get ReferencedEnvelope from the Tile and would ask for the lower and upper corner coords and that would be it but... `findTileAtCoordinate(...)` needs parameter of type `org.geotools.tile.TileService` and in order to create `WMTSTileService` object I need to pass a bunch of parameters among which is `org.geotools.data.wmts.model.TileMatrixSet`. Now I don't want to manually parse WMTS capabilities document to create `TileMatrixSet` object. I would expect there should be a way to create service which needs only GeoServer address and a layer name so it could fetch all the data about layer (BoundingBox, EPSGCode, TileMatrixSet and so on) so I could pass them to `WMTSTileFactory.findTileAtCoordinate(...)`. Is there a such service? Maybe I am doing wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC (and I was supposed to document this last year) you need to create a `WMSTSTileService` which takes the base URL of the server. You can then either issue a `getTiles` request or grab the `TileMatrixSet` from it using `getTileMatrixSet()`.

```
    String serverURL="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?"
    WebMapTileServer wmts = new WebMapTileServer(serverURL);
    WMTSCapabilities capabilities = wmts.getCapabilities();
    WMTSLayer layer = (WMTSLayer) capabilities.getLayer("topp:states");

    request.setLayer(layer);

    request.setRequestedWidth(800);
    request.setRequestedHeight(400);

    String format = "image/png";
    List<String> formats = layer.getFormats();

    if (!formats.contains("image/png")) {
        format = (String) formats.get(0);
    }
    request.setFormat(format);

    ReferencedEnvelope re = new ReferencedEnvelope(-180, 180, -90, 90, CRS.decode("EPSG:4326"));
    request.setRequestedBBox(re);

    // System.out.println(request.getFinalURL());
    Set<Tile> responses = (Set<Tile>) wmts.issueRequest(request);

    for (Tile response : responses) {
        // System.out.println("Content Type: " + response.getContentType());
        // System.out.println(response.getTileIdentifier());
        BufferedImage image = response.getBufferedImage();
        //do what ever you want with the image.
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to get capabilities of a single layer (without removing "Advertised" flag for unwanted layers)? I am asking this because when current capabilities document is being parsed I get `Parsing failed for MinTileRow: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value '-3' must be non-negative (0 or above).` I have checked - a number of layers have negative values for `MinTileRow` in the current capabilities document.

Comment: that sounds like a bug on the server, negative tile numbers seem to make no sense. But, no there is no way to get layer info without parsing the whole capabilities document.

Comment: Uh, one problem after another.....